# Possible to assign categories to my nextgen Gallery in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I want to add categories to my galleries so that in a sidebar widget I could list my categories and clicking on that category would bring up all the galleries under that category.  Is this possible?  If not with nextgen then with anything else?

Answer (score 0):

In NextGen you can create differents and call them in widget, there a drop-down will appear and choose any category from there and switch to that one...